# How do I find a polynomial in a field?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

If I have a polynomial:

$$f(x) = c_0 x^0 + c_1 x^1 + c_2 x^2 + \dots + c_n x^n$$

How can I find the polynomial, modulo a prime number $p$?  In other words, I want to take all of the coefficients modulo $p$, and all of the powers modulo $p-1$.  So, for instance, the result modulo 3 would be:

$$(c_0 \bmod 3)x^0+$$
$$(c_1 \bmod 3)x^1+$$
$$(c_2 \bmod 3)x^0+$$
$$(c_3 \bmod 3)x^1+$$
$$(c_4 \bmod 3)x^0+$$
$$(c_5 \bmod 3)x^1+$$
$$\dots$$

Please note that this is just an example, and in general **I want to find any polynomial modulo any prime $p$.**

So, in general, I have something like:

```
 5 + 13x + 14x^2 + 7x^3 + 8x^4
```

I want to take all powers of $x$ modulo $p-1$, so I get:

```
 5 + 13x + 14 + 7x + 8
```

...which, in turn, equals, by simplifying:

```
 27 + 20x
```

Then, taking all coefficients modulo 3, we get:

```
 0 + 2x
```

How can I code this?

Comment: Is this Question about the Software Mathematica? If so please complement your Question with Code. Else [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions) satisfies your needs better.

Comment: @Louis:  This question is about code, although the right mathematics could make a difference, too.  I've added code to show an example of what I'm after.

Comment: matt, please fix your example and/or clarify why you accepted an answer that gives a different result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an equation

```
    eqn = 5 + 13 x + 14 x^2 + 7 x^3 + 8 x^4
```

We can simply apply a rule to all integers, replacing them the new `Mod` value. As follows:

```
    eqn /. x_ /; IntegerQ[x] :> Mod[x, 3]
```

Which gives:

```
    3 + 3 x + 2 x^2
```

The example you give in your question doesn't seem to tally with what you initially describe as your goal?

If you only want to apply the `Mod` to the exponents, then:

```
   eqn /. Power[x_, y_] :> Power[x, Mod[y, 3]]
```

Which gives:

```
    12 + 21 x + 14 x^2
```

Comment: Note the `x` I've used in my rule has nothing to do with the `x` in the equation! That was a poor choice of symbol on my part!

Comment: This works, because I want to take the powers mod $p-1$, which you've done in the second part, followed by the coefficients (including the constant) modulo $p$.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Should be something like this:

```
poly = 5 + 13 x + 14 x^2 + 7 x^3 + 8 x^4;
p = 3;
Total@MapIndexed[# x^Mod[First@#2 - 1, p - 1] &, 
  Mod[#, p] & /@ CoefficientList[poly, x]]
```

> 6 + 2 x

(I don't follow your example though.. maybe I missed something )